# Cumulative distribution function of Y1 and Y2

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given scenario: Jim invites two friends J and W to a party. The arrival times of the two friends are independent and each is uniformly distributed over an hour starting from 19:00. Define the following: 

Y1 = time elapsed since 19:00 until the first of the two friends arrives. 

Y2: the time elapsed since 19:00 until the second of the two friends arrives.

How do you show that (over some region) the joint cdf of Y1 and Y2 is given by $2y_{1}y_{2} - (y_{1})^2$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $Y_1=\min\{Y_J,Y_W\}$ and $Y_2=\max\{Y_J,Y_W\}$ where $Y_J$ is the time elapsed since 19:00 when J arrives and $Y_W$ is the time elapsed since 19:00 when W arrives (both measured in hours). Thus, $(Y_J,Y_W)$ is uniform on $(0,1)^2$, and, for every $x\lt y$ in $(0,1)$,
$$
P(x\lt Y_1,Y_2\lt y)=P(x\lt Y_J\lt y,x\lt Y_W\lt y)=(y-x)^2.
$$
Differentiating twice yields the density $f_{Y_1,Y_2}$ of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ as
$$
f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=2\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt y_1\lt y_2\lt 1}.
$$
Thus, for every $0\lt y_1\lt y_2\lt1$,
$$
P(Y_1\lt y_1,Y_2\lt y_2)=\int_0^{y_2}\int_0^{y_1}f_{Y_1,Y_2}(u,v)\mathrm du\mathrm dv=\int_0^{y_2}\int_0^{\min\{y_1,v\}}2\mathrm du\mathrm dv,
$$
that is,
$$
P(Y_1\lt y_1,Y_2\lt y_2)=\int_0^{y_2}2\min\{y_1,v\}\mathrm dv=\int_0^{y_1}2v\mathrm dv+\int_{y_1}^{y_2}2y_1\mathrm dv,
$$
that is, 
$$
P(Y_1\lt y_1,Y_2\lt y_2)=y_1^2+2y_1(y_2-y_1)=2y_1y_2-y_1^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Did is right I wrote an answer before which was completely wrong but I think I found an alternative method to find the pdf which is just the first step.

Since $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are order statistics the joint pdf is given by
$$f_{(1),(2)}(y_1,y_2)=\frac{2!}{(1-1)!(2-1-1)!(2-2)!}(y_1)^0(y_2-y_1)^0(y_2)^0f_{(1)}(y_1)f_{(2)}(y_2)=2$$

Comment: "$f_{Y_1}(y_1)=f_{Y_2}(y_2)=1$" No. "they're independent" They are not.

Comment: Yeah you're right that was stupid of me!!  I think I've fixed it up to provide an alternative method.  Could you please let me know if I'm correct now?

Comment: Well, now most of the post is about something else... but the last displayed formula is incorrect on several counts (starting from the left, note that $F(Y_1,Y_2)$ is a random variable). For a correct formulation, see the first identity involving $P(Y_1\lt y_1,Y_2\lt y_2)$ in my post.

Comment: Ok thanks for your feedback... obviously I need to practice this lol since its going to be in my next exam.  Was also wondering the logic behind this step... $$\int^{y_2}_02min{(y_1,v)}dv=\int^{y_1}_{0}2vdv+\int^{v}_{0}2vdv$$  I think I almost understand it but just wanted to get your explanation to make sure I'm understanding it correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what you almost understand in it. Then I can confirm. (By the way these should be comments on the other answer.)

Comment: Sorry I tried to comment on your answer but don't have enough reputation.  Yeah sorry made a mistake in my last comment it was this line:$$P(Y_1\lt y_1,Y_2\lt y_2)=\int_0^{y_2}2\min\{y_1,v\}\mathrm dv=\int_0^{y_1}2v\mathrm dv+\int_{y_1}^{y_2}2y_1\mathrm dv$$  I thought this was because if $v<y_1$ we integrate from 0 to $y_1$ because this is the only range v can fall into.  And then if $y_1<v$ we integrate from $y_1$ to $y_2$ since v can then take any value up to the large order statistic $y_2$.  This is just me making my best guess though...

Comment: And also I had a question in class where we had to find the joint density of three order statistics and integrate over the 2nd order statistic to find the joint density of the 1st and 3rd order statistics.  Would this same technique apply here too?

Comment: Sure, it is always the same thing.

Comment: Ok thanks heaps!!